# How would you loop this class call and plot?

Tags: python, class, matplotlib, differential-equations

So I have a code with a lot of redundant values, I am supposed to graph 8 different curves into the same plot, could I solve it with a nice for loop?
Notice that the only difference I have here is the last value in the `linspace`.

```
t1=np.linspace(0,10,20)
t2=np.linspace(0,10,30)
t3=np.linspace(0,10,35)
t4=np.linspace(0,10,40)
t5=np.linspace(0,10,50)
t6=np.linspace(0,10,100)
t7=np.linspace(0,10,1000)
t8=np.linspace(0,10,10000)

u1,t1=fe.solve(t1)
u2,t2=fe.solve(t2)
u3,t3=fe.solve(t3)
u4,t4=fe.solve(t4)
u5,t5=fe.solve(t5)
u6,t6=fe.solve(t6)
u7,t7=fe.solve(t7)
u8,t8=fe.solve(t8)

#plot
plt.plot(t1,u1, label="20")
plt.plot(t2,u2, label="30")
plt.plot(t3,u3, label="35")
plt.plot(t4,u4, label="40")
plt.plot(t5,u5, label="50")
plt.plot(t6,u6, label="100")
plt.plot(t7,u7, label="1000")
plt.plot(t8,u8, label="10000")
```

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that a simple for loop is all that is needed, something very simple like

```
sizes = [10, 20, 35, 40, 50, 100, 1000, 10000]
for size in sizes:
    t = np.linspace(0, 10, size)
    u, t = fe.solve(t)
    plt.plot(t, u, label=str(size))
```

Its possible you may even be able to do it without a for loop using `np.array` depending on the fe library you are using, but the above certainly makes the code more manageable.

I would advise looking up iteration in python, I see you are a fairly new contributor so suspect you may also be new to python also - for loops will save you a lot of time writing out very similar processes!

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what "fe" is so I cannot test my code, but could you try

```py
values = [20,30,34,40,50,100,1000,100000]
results = {value: fe.solve(np.linspace(0,10, value)) for value in values}
for value, (u, t) in results.items():
  plt.plot(t, u, label=str(value))
```

Another solution : I used a dictionnary comprehension since I wanted to avoid for-loop but since I use one anyway to plot, might as well go all-in

```py
for value in [20,30,34,40,50,100,1000,100000]:
  t = np.linspace(0,10,value)
  u, t = fe.solve(t)
  plt.plot(t, u, label=str(value)
```

Comment: for times, (u, t) in curves.items():

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Comment: Add me on discord and ill send the entire code Shotta#9200

Comment: Yeah that was my bad I totally forgot the "fe.solve" there, it should work now